# Can't connect to Cassandra using Astyanax - Frame size (352518912) larger than max length (16384000)!

Tags: cassandra, thrift, astyanax

I'm having issues connecting to cassandra with mutagen/astyanax.

```
    CassandraMutagen mutagen = new CassandraMutagenImpl();

    mutagen.initialize("/mutations");

    AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> ctx = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
            .forKeyspace("anser")
            .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("aConfig")
               .setSeeds("localhost")
               .setPort(9160))
            .withAstyanaxConfiguration(
                new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
                    .setConnectionPoolType(ConnectionPoolType.TOKEN_AWARE)
                    .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE))
            .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());
    ctx.start();
    Keyspace keyspace = ctx.getClient();      
    Plan.Result<Integer> result = mutagen.mutate(keyspace);
```

And when i try to connect i get the exception:

```
com.toddfast.mutagen.MutagenException: Could not create column family "schema_version"
at com.toddfast.mutagen.cassandra.CassandraSubject.getCurrentState(CassandraSubject.java:79)
at com.toddfast.mutagen.cassandra.CassandraCoordinator.accept(CassandraCoordinator.java:48)
at com.toddfast.mutagen.basic.BasicPlanner.getPlan(BasicPlanner.java:66)
at com.toddfast.mutagen.cassandra.impl.CassandraPlanner.getPlan(CassandraPlanner.java:153)
at com.toddfast.mutagen.cassandra.impl.CassandraMutagenImpl.mutate(CassandraMutagenImpl.java:100)
at com.salesforce.analytics.cc.CassandraChangeControlTests2.test_mutagen(CassandraChangeControlTests2.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.TransportException: TransportException: [host=localhost(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=2(2), attempts=1]org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (352518912) larger than max length (16384000)!
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:197)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:137)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:119)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:338)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.executeDdlOperation(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:511)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.internalCreateColumnFamily(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:790)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.createColumnFamily(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:580)
at com.toddfast.mutagen.cassandra.CassandraSubject.createSchemaVersionTable(CassandraSubject.java:53)
at com.toddfast.mutagen.cassandra.CassandraSubject.getCurrentState(CassandraSubject.java:76)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Frame size (352518912) larger than max length (16384000)!
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:137)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:608)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.set_keyspace(Cassandra.java:595)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:125)
... 36 more
```

I tried changing the frame size settings in my cassandra.yaml to

```
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 360
thrift_max_message_length_in_mb: 361
```

And can see this reflected in the startup logs.  However, I still get the same framesize exception.

My cassandra is 2.1.12, and my deps are

```
<dependency org="com.toddfast.mutagen" name="mutagen-cassandra" rev="0.4.0" conf="master->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.cassandra" name="cassandra-all" rev="2.1.12" conf="master->default"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see that you also have to set it client side, and the version of astyanax that mutagen-cassandra is built with (1.56.44) is too old to allow configuration  going to rebuild from source!

See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201504.mbox/%3CCAORswtx9UJvW6aexT1N6tuxzCLBVJL7JCXfJ=DUX3cvMSsgiJw@mail.gmail.com%3E